# Distribute points between 0 and 1 over a wider area using weighting

Tags: python

I presume this isn't too hard if you know what you are doing, but my last implementation wasn't perfect, and the weighting broke if you did it on the extremes, and now I can't make sense of it.

Basically, everything has a value between 0 and 1, and I need to assign them to a shader. Here is a basic idea of how it will work

```
numShaders = 20

i = 0
weight = 0.5
shader = 0

i = 0.5
weight = 0.5
shader = 10

i = 1
weight = 0.5
shader = 20

i = 1
weight = 0
shader = 0

i = 0.5
weight = 0.75
shader = around 15

i = 1
weight = 0.75
shader = 20
```

The weighting should be exponential (or ideally have an option to control how pushed out it is - eg. pushed out would mean 0.75 weight could produce 17 instead of 15, but still never go over 20 ), and only result in everything using the same shader if it is set at 0 or 1 (or close enough to it).

I've been trying to figure it but have had no luck currently, so thanks in advance.

If it helps, this works for a weight of 0.5, but not for the other weights, I'm not quite sure where you'd add the power - `numShaders*weight*i*2`

Also the old implementation is here, I'm just unable to translate the initial parts successfully into something that works now (once I have the basics I'll probably be able to replicate the rest of this) -

```
#colourValue = 0 to 1
#shaderAmount = number of shaders in total
#colourExponential = pushing values inwards to give solid colours at edges
#colourRatio = weight

#calculate colour to assign
colourValue = py.getAttr( cube+'.colourValue' )
colourNum = colourValue * shaderAmount - ( (colourValue * shaderAmount) - shaderAmount/2.0 ) / colourExponential

if stretchValues == True:
    #stretch out the values from 0 to max
    if colourNum + 1 == colourNumHalf:
        factor = 0
    elif colourNum + 1 < colourNumHalf:
        factor = ( -colourNumMin / float( colourNum + 1 ) ) * colourNumMin
    elif colourNum + 1 > colourNumHalf:
        factor = ( colourNumMax / float( shaderAmount - colourNum + 1 ) ) * colourNumMax
else:
    factor = 0

colourNum = int(colourNum + factor)

#fix to stop negative numbers
if colourNum < 0:
    colourNum = -colourNum

#set ratio of colours
if colourRatio > 0.5:
    colourNum = int( colourNum + ( shaderAmount - colourNum ) ** ( colourRatio * 2 - 1 ) )
elif colourRatio < 0.5:
    colourNum = int( colourNum - colourNum ** ( 1 - colourRatio * 2 ) )

colourNum = int(round(colourNum,0))

#stop invalid values
if colourNum < 0:
    colourNum = 0
elif colourNum >= shaderAmount:
    colourNum = shaderAmount - 1

py.select( shaderName + str(colourNum), noExpand = True )

#check previous shader
try:
    oldShader.append(shaderSelect.split('n')[-1])
except:
    oldShader.append(shaderAmount - 1)

shaderSelect = py.ls( selection = True )[0]

#stop big jumps in colour
if int(shaderSelect.split('n')[-1]) < int(oldShader[-1]) - 1:
    py.select( shaderName + str(int(oldShader[-1])-1), noExpand = True )
    #overrides initial calculation for extra smoothness
    for i in range(smoothOverride):
        if len(oldShader) > (i+1):
            if int(oldShader[-1]) != int(oldShader[-2-i]):
                py.select( shaderName + str(int(oldShader[-1])), noExpand = True )
    shaderSelect = py.ls( selection = True )[0]
```

Edit: As Evert pointed out, it's actually normal distribution I'm after, I'm going to attempt to code something similar to this graph, but with 0.5 as the middle point, and 0 and 1 as the extremes. I'll edit the question again if I'm successful.
[image]

Comment: Can you list anything you've tried yourself so far?

Comment: `20/9 * (1 * 10**i - 1)`.

Comment: I updated it with the old version I did now, and thanks, but where did that 9 come from Evert? :P

Comment: `9 = 10**1 - 10**0`, with the exponents 0 and 1 the numbers from your initial range. (As a matter of fact, the 1 at the end is `10**0` in this case). The 20 is obviously your final range. While this gives you a widened, exponentially-weighted, range, this does of course result in non-integer numbers, and  rounding or truncating numbers will result double numbers. It's up to you how you'd like to fix that.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I get that now, I just tried it though and while it is exponentially weighted, it's unfortunately not balanced (should stretch out either end, not just at higher numbers). I'll have a play around and see if I can reverse it for weights under 0.5 :)

Comment: Exponential *and* stretching out at either end doesn't really sound exponential. Perhaps you're thinking of a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), or `1 - Normal(x)`?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I suppose I'm after that cumulative distribution function graph (thanks for the link, had no idea what I should have called it), just a shame it's all maths notation haha, I'll have to look up how to do it in a bit :)